# Slow internet connection on Mac OS

Tags: windows-7, macos, router, internet-connection

At home, we have a router. From router goes the internet connection into the desktop PC (Windows 7) and Macbook Pro.

The problem is, that on Mac OS is incredibly slow internet connection - is not possible to use the laptop for surfing on the internet. The same as for WiFi as for cable.

On the PC with Windows 7 is working the internet connection properly.

Is there any tool for testing, if on my Mac is a virus or just something, what slowing down the internet connection?

THank you in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that the internet is slow only over WiFi?  Have you tried plugging the MacBook into the router directly with an ethernet cable?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your speed at [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) to compare the difference in Internet speeds between each computer.

You can also try using the Network Diagnotic tool:

1. Open *System Preferences*
2. Select *Network*
3. Click the button *Assist Me*
4. Select *Diagnostics to troubleshoot your problem*

Comment: 2 things I'd like to add: a) Look at the interface with `ifconfig`, are any values of errors, dropped, overrun, frame carrier non-zero? b) Look at the traffic with wireshark. Are there excessive DNS lookups? Checksum errors? As asked above, can you connect the macbook to the router via cable?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your replies, I am going to try it. `can you connect the macbook to the router via cable?` -> yes, I can. And if I do it, the internet connection is working correctly, without any problem. Looks like a problem is between macbook and router.